# Golang go routine run, but different from what i expected

Tags: go, goroutine

so i have this simple go routine code

```
func jobX(wg *sync.WaitGroup)  {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        fmt.Println("routine X: ", i)
        if i == 2 {
            time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        }
    }
}

func jobY()  {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        fmt.Println("routine Y: ", i)
    }
}

func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    fmt.Println("starting go routine...")

    wg.Add(1)
    go jobX(&wg)
    jobY()

    fmt.Println("end")

    wg.Wait()
}
```

when i run the program, this is the result:

starting go routine...
routine Y:  0
routine Y:  1
routine Y:  2
routine Y:  3
routine Y:  4
end
routine X:  0
routine X:  1
routine X:  2
routine X:  3
routine X:  4

but this is what i expect it to be:

starting go routine...
routine X:  0
routine X:  1
routine X:  2
routine Y:  0
routine Y:  1
routine Y:  2
routine Y:  3
routine Y:  4
routine X:  3
routine X:  4
end

i cant figure it out how should i change my code to get this result.

Comment: Why do you want or expect this output? Do you understand that there is _no_ synchronisation between the different print statements and that they thus _are_ unsynchronised?

Comment: hi, @Volker so im new to this language and still trying to understand go routines, and i want to execute jobX() and jobY() concurrently, i already try change "jobY()" to "go jobY()" but always got different results, is there any workaround to achieve that always same result i expected?

Comment: You cannot do that w go routines directly. The go routine execution scheduling is not deterministic. When your X routines which run in a separate virtual thread will run will be dependent on the machine you executing on and other parameters. If you want a specific order either don't use virtual threads or you need a synchronization mechnism such as a mutex or semafor.

Comment: "i want to execute jobX() and jobY() concurrently" you do. "but always got different results" that's basically the meaning of "concurrent" as opposed to "serial" . "is there any workaround to achieve that always same result" yes: run your code non-concurrent. "result i expected" you have to adapt your expectations to reality.

Comment: @Volker ok, so its impossible with concurrent then, thanks for your answer.

(@)Ivasan i dont know much about mutex and semafor, but i will try to read it first, thanks.

Comment: @Mirana, it's not that it's impossible, it's that it probably doesn't make sense to do so. You would need to add a bunch of synchronization (https://go.dev/play/p/hluUzZ2A4lG) in order to ensure that these events happen _serially_, so why are you using concurrency at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to ensure that end is called after everything is run, then you need to move the `wg.Wait()` to in front of your `fmt.Println("end")`:

```
func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    fmt.Println("starting go routine...")

    wg.Add(1)
    go jobX(&wg)
    jobY()

    wg.Wait() // <-- change

    fmt.Println("end")
}
```

You cannot expect a specific output when using goroutines.

Check out this [blog post](https://www.codingexplorations.com/blog/mastering-the-art-of-goroutines-and-channels-unleashing-gos-concurrency-superpowers) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

You need a second increment of your `waitGroup` for your `Y`, and then you also need to move the `Wait` up before the "end":

```golang
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    fmt.Println("starting go routine...")

    wg.Add(1)
    go jobX(&wg)

    wg.Add(1)
    go jobY(&wg)

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("end")
```

...and make the corresponding changes to your `jobY` func so it can call `wg.Done()` like `jobX` is.